# Get HTML from XSLT and XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a XML file and a XSLT style-sheet for styling. If I run the file in the Browser, the Browser runs an HTML file. (I have html tags in the XSLT stylesheet). I would like to somehow generate this HTML file locally, so that I can send it to people via email. (It is a test result report).

How can I do this? I don't want to send XML and XSLT file, only HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use an xslt processor like [xsltproc](http://libxml.org) (maybe in your linux distro or even cygwin),  [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (may also be in your linux distro), [xalan](http://xalan.apache.org) (in java runs anywhere)

The exact cmd line differs  but all get an xml and an xslt and produce xml, html or text output (you probably have `<xsl:output method="html"/>` in your code, some will autodetect or have cmd line options for specifying the desired output form).